# PHP script affecting local system storage

Tags: php, sql, windows, postgresql

I have a curious issue that is happening on my system when I run a PHP program I created.  I am taking data from two tables and doing a comparison of data from Table A with Table B.  If the record is not in Table A, then write that record to Table B.  I discovered that the program works fine but, at least one record has to be in Table B first.  After my first successful run Table A will have 16000+ records in it, now Table B has 15000+ or so records.  I understand that there is going to be a bit of time for this to process.  The curious thing is I noticed my hard drive is losing free space as the program runs.  I have tried manually running the garbage collection.  I also looked where the session files are being stored, only to find a few files that are rather small in size.  I also tried adjusting the length of time that session files are stored from 1440 seconds to 30 secs. When I say that I am "losing" free space, there is something that is filling up my hard drive.  I have gone from having 6GB to 5.75GB, if I allow the program to run longer, I only lose more space. I have also tried just simply restarting my system and I only regain a small portion of the space I lost. At this point I am unsure what I need to do to stop this from happening. Here is a sample of my code below:

```
<?php

include('./connect_local_pdo.php'); //Includes DB Connection Script
ini_set('max_execution_time', 5400); //5400 seconds = 90 minutes
gc_disable();

try {


$tbl_a_data = $conn->prepare('SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c from table_a');
$tbl_a_data->execute();


$tbl_b_data = $conn->prepare('SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c from table_b');
$tbl_b_data->execute();
$tbl_b_array = $tbl_b_data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


while($tbl_a_array = $tbl_a_data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){


    foreach ($tbl_b_array as $tbl_b_array2){

        if ($tbl_a_array['col_a'] !== $tbl_b_array2['col_a']){

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table_b 
                                              (col_a, col_b, col_c)
                                              VALUES 
                                              (:col_a, :col_b, :col_c)");

            $stmt->bindParam(':col_a', $tbl_a_array['col_a']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':col_b', $tbl_a_array['col_b']);
            $stmt->bindParam(':col_c', $tbl_a_array['col_c']);


            $stmt->execute();

        } else {

                $stmt = $conn->prepare("update table_b
                                              set 
                                                col_b = table_a.col_b,
                                                col_c = table_a.col_c                                                    
                                            from table_a
                                            where table_b.col_a = table_a.col_a ");

                $stmt -> execute();


            }
        }
    }

gc_collect_cycles();
gc_mem_caches();
clearstatcache();


} catch (PDOException $a) {

   echo $a->getMessage();//Remove or change message in production code

}
```

Any assistance with this will be greatly appreciated!  As of this post I have lost 2 gigs of space running this program.

Comment: Where is the Database? Same System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your line

```
include('./connect_local_pdo.php'); //Includes DB Connection Script
```

I assume it is a Database on localhost.

The Database is growing with your entries. It will take space to add rows.

Comment: Thank you!  You put me on the right track for getting this sorted out.  It was the log files!  I'll write a PHP script to maintain this moving forward.  I just reclaimed 32 gigs of space!